# How to remove an item in a dict of a list that doesn't exist in a specific list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to eliminate some dict-item that doesn't meet my requirement, specifically: 
I have the below list

```
[{'parameters': ['int', 'int'], 'function': 'checkIndex'},
 {'parameters': ['int'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['float'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['boolean'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['long'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['double'], 'function': 'valueOf'}]
```

but I only want to have those whose items are among ['float', 'double'],

I have tried the following way:

```
for i in a :
    for c in i['parameters']:
        if c not in ['int', 'float']:
            a.remove(i)
        else:
            continue
```

but it didn't eliminate all the things I don't want, so I wonder what's the proper way out?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you remove items from the list you're looping over?

Comment: You said you want to eliminate all but float and double so why are you doing for c not in [int, float]?

Comment: Also it is not a good idea to remove elements from a list you are looping. You'd better create an other list.

Comment: The text and code contradict each other. Do you only want those dicts that have float and in't, or float and double in their parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [{'parameters': ['int', 'int'], 'function': 'checkIndex'},
 {'parameters': ['int'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['float'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['boolean'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['long'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['double'], 'function': 'valueOf'}]

new_list = []
for d in l:
    if any(p not in {'int', 'float'} for p in d['parameters']):
        continue
    new_list.append(d)

print(new_list)
```

This seems like a fast approach, but it does create a new list. Using `any` over `all` to break out quickly when possible.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with `Never modify a list you are iterating on`, so use another list to save your results, also check for float and double in `parameters` key, instead of checking for `not int or float`, since checking by process of elimination is always worse than checking for a condition directly!

```
a = [{'parameters': ['int', 'int'], 'function': 'checkIndex'},
 {'parameters': ['int'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['float'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['boolean'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['long'], 'function': 'valueOf'},
 {'parameters': ['double'], 'function': 'valueOf'}]

res = []
#Iterate on a but save result on another list
for i in a:
    #Use any to check for parameters being float or double in parameters key
    if any([p in ['float', 'double'] for p in i['parameters']]):
        res.append(i)

print(res)
```

The output will then be.

```
[{'parameters': ['float'], 'function': 'valueOf'}, {'parameters': ['double'], 'function': 'valueOf'}]
```

Comment: Best to stick with generator expressions rather than list comprehension when you're using 'any'.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please accept or upvote my answer if it helped you:)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please accept or upvote my answer if it helped you :) which is the tick next to the answer!